# In REST Assured, how do I use a map of parameters?

Tags: java, rest, hashmap, rest-assured, getresponse

Issue:

```
Response resp = given().headers(headerElements).param("language", "en").and().param("currency", "***").and()
            .param("destination", "**").and().param("theme", Arrays.asList(arr)).and().param("order", "1").and()
            .param("partner", "***").and().param("pageNumber", "1").and().param("pageSize", "20").when().get(uri);
```

This works completely fine and gives me the desired result for further assertion.

But if i send the parameters as a Map it doesnt give me the desired result.

```
Response resp = given().headers(headerElements).params(m).when().get(uri);

m.put("language", "en");
m.put("currency", "**");
m.put("destination", "***");
m.put("theme", Arrays.asList(theme_list_1));
m.put("order", "1");
m.put("partner", "***");
m.put("pageSize", "20");
m.put("pageNumber", "1");
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the official documentation of rest assured, there is a way of passing multiple values for a single parameter, BUT NO way of passing key value pairs themselves.

[https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#parameters]

However, you can pass multiple values as a string; like this:

```
.param("language", "en", "currency", "**", "destination", "***")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my tests and your solution seems right. The only difference I see are the values in your first request

```
.param("currency", "***").and().param("destination", "**")
```

from the second request

```
m.put("currency", "**");
m.put("destination", "***");
```

Currency and destination have different number of *. Perhaps this might the problem?